# Can't Install Python Package onto Docker

Tags: python, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose

Trying to install a package (flake8) onto a Docker container (or maybe it's an image). I've pip installed the package locally, and when I try to pip install it again, I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: flake8 in c:\python39\lib\site-packages (5.0.4)
```

But then when I run this code snippet:

```
docker-compose run --rm app sh -c "flake8"
```

I get the following error:

```
sh: flake8: not found
```

Using VSCode. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Given that the "Requirement already satisfied" message is giving you a C: path, this makes me suspect that you may have installed flake8 on your Windows host system. You need to make sure you're installing `flake8` in the Docker container itself.

Comment: Isn't the 2nd command above used to install it on the container?

Comment: You should install things in your _image_; the `docker-compose run` command you show just launches a temporary container based on the image, with the source code and tools preinstalled.  Does your Dockerfile install this tool, either because you have a specific `RUN pip install flake8` line or it's in a `requirements.txt` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Flake8 was only installed locally as opposed to on the Docker image (See David's comment above for more on this).

To remedy this, the following line was added to a requirements.txt file (the numbers were for the version of the package):

```
flake8>=3.9.2,<3.10
```

And then in the Dockerfile:

```
/py/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt && \
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command to install in the docker container instead of in the base environment:

```
pip install flake8
```

Comment: In this case I'm not looking to install it in the docker container. Just in the dev environment.